# Jquery fadein/out of overlay covering input box: input fields sit on top of overlay until animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big overlay that fades in over the top of a form after it is submitted, giving the effect of the entire form "greying out", and the text boxes becoming locked (at least superficially).  However, the input fields seem to sit on top of the overlay until after the animation ends, and then instantly pop back under the overlay.  So, rather than the textboxes gradually becoming greyed out (like the area around them is), their contrast instantly changes at the end of the animation (tested with the overlay fading in over 10 seconds).

Is this a known bug?  The z-levels are set correctly, so I'm not really sure what could be causing the problem...

edit: I don't think I can really give an example without pasting my entire code, but one very strange observation is that if I disable the jq_watermark plugin for all input boxes, one of them is fixed and behaves properly but the rest are still bugged.  I've stripped them all of css styles and still all but one are bugged in this way.  Very odd.

Comment: Sounds like a browser bug to me.  What browser(s) does this happen with?

Comment: This happens in both Chrome and Firefox (although I haven't tested it in any other browser yet)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) issue. Setting the `position` or `opacity < 1` on an element puts it in a new stacking context. This means that while it is fading, it may have a different stacking context because the `opacity` is less than 1, or because jquery is changing the `position` while running the animation and then changing it back when it's done. Hard to say for sure though without seeing it for myself.

Things to try:

- Change the order of the overlay vs. the form elements in the source code.
- Wrap the overlay in a `div` with `position:relative`.
- Fade to `0.9` instead of fully in order to see wether it is a stacking context issue caused by `opacity < 1` or if it is caused by jquery setting the `position`.
- Make sure all elements on which you are using `z-index` are positioned using `position`. `z-index` only applies to elements with a position set.